# Iterate List Names Using apply()

Tags: r, list, lapply, paste

I'm trying to use lapply to run a linear model with a bunch of outputs. It's hard for me to tell which output belongs to which pair of parameters so I'd like to paste in the list names with each output. Here's some data:

```
Site    Date    Season  Species BodySize    Mass    SeasonGDD
1   3/19/17 winter  infrequens  6   1.134965577 3.556416667
1   3/19/17 winter  infrequens  6   1.134965577 3.556416667
1   3/19/17 winter  infrequens  6   1.134965577 3.556416667
1   3/19/17 winter  infrequens  6   1.134965577 3.556416667
1   3/19/17 winter  infrequens  6   1.134965577 3.556416667
1   3/19/17 winter  infrequens  6.2 1.245407892 3.556416667
1   3/19/17 winter  infrequens  6.2 1.245407892 3.556416667
1   3/19/17 winter  infrequens  6.2 1.245407892 3.556416667
1   3/19/17 winter  infrequens  6.4 1.362573803 3.556416667
1   3/19/17 winter  infrequens  6.4 1.362573803 3.556416667
1   3/19/17 winter  doddsii 6.4 1.362573803 3.556416667
1   3/19/17 winter  infrequens  6.4 1.362573803 3.556416667
1   3/19/17 winter  infrequens  6.4 1.362573803 3.556416667
4   3/19/17 winter  infrequens  6.4 1.362573803 3.556416667
4   3/19/17 winter  doddsii 6.6 1.486643287 3.556416667
3   3/19/17 winter  infrequens  6.6 1.486643287 3.556416667
2   3/19/17 winter  infrequens  6.6 1.486643287 3.556416667
2   3/19/17 winter  infrequens  6.6 1.486643287 3.556416667
1   3/19/17 winter  infrequens  6.6 1.486643287 3.556416667
1   3/19/17 winter  infrequens  6.6 1.486643287 3.556416667
1   3/19/17 winter  doddsii 6.6 1.486643287 3.556416667
1   3/19/17 winter  doddsii 6.6 1.486643287 3.556416667
1   3/19/17 winter  cockerelli  6.8 1.293245066 3.556416667
5   3/19/17 winter  infrequens  6.8 1.617795375 3.556416667
5   3/19/17 winter  infrequens  6.8 1.617795375 3.556416667
3   3/19/17 winter  infrequens  6.8 1.617795375 3.556416667
1   3/19/17 winter  infrequens  6.8 1.617795375 3.556416667
5   3/19/17 winter  doddsii     6.8 1.617795375 3.556416667
4   3/19/17 winter  grandis     6.9 1.347971145 3.556416667
1   3/19/17 winter  doddsii     7   1.75620819  3.556416667
1   3/19/17 winter  infrequens  7   1.75620819  3.556416667
1   3/19/17 winter  infrequens  7   1.75620819  3.556416667
1   3/19/17 winter  infrequens  7   1.75620819  3.556416667
1   3/19/17 winter  doddsii     7.2 1.902058976 3.556416667
1   3/19/17 winter  infrequens  7.2 1.902058976 3.556416667
2   3/19/17 winter  infrequens  7.2 1.902058976 3.556416667
2   3/19/17 winter  doddsii     7.4 2.055524128 3.556416667
2   3/19/17 winter  doddsii     7.4 2.055524128 3.556416667
2   3/19/17 winter  doddsii     7.4 2.055524128 3.556416667
1   3/19/17 winter  doddsii     7.4 2.055524128 3.556416667
1   3/19/17 winter  doddsii     7.4 2.055524128 3.556416667
1   3/19/17 winter  cockerelli  7.5 1.707996411 3.556416667
1   3/19/17 winter  doddsii     7.6 2.216779222 3.556416667
3   3/19/17 winter  doddsii     7.6 2.216779222 3.556416667
4   3/19/17 winter  doddsii     7.6 2.216779222 3.556416667
1   3/19/17 winter  infrequens  7.6 2.216779222 3.556416667
1   3/19/17 winter  cockerelli  7.7 1.840497347 3.556416667
1   3/19/17 winter  doddsii 7.8 2.385999034 3.556416667
2   3/19/17 winter  doddsii 7.8 2.385999034 3.556416667
2   3/19/17 winter  doddsii 7.8 2.385999034 3.556416667
3   3/19/17 winter  doddsii 8.2 2.749028097 3.556416667
1   3/19/17 winter  doddsii 8.6 3.145994526 3.556416667
5   3/19/17 winter  cockerelli  8.7 2.603054046 3.556416667
1   3/19/17 winter  doddsii 9   3.578270231 3.556416667
5   3/19/17 winter  doddsii 9.4 4.047216436 3.556416667
5   3/19/17 winter  cockerelli  9.7 3.545136654 3.556416667
5   3/19/17 winter  cockerelli  10.6    4.560698666 3.556416667
4   3/19/17 winter  cockerelli  10.8    4.80925792  3.556416667
4   3/19/17 winter  grandis 10.8    4.80925792  3.556416667
4   3/19/17 winter  cockerelli  10.9    4.936758182 3.556416667
1   3/19/17 winter  cockerelli  11  5.066427825 3.556416667
2   3/19/17 winter  cockerelli  11  5.066427825 3.556416667
1   3/19/17 winter  grandis 11  5.066427825 3.556416667
1   3/19/17 winter  cockerelli  11.2    5.332341968 3.556416667
2   3/19/17 winter  cockerelli  11.5    5.747899893 3.556416667
```

Here's my code now:

```
newdata = split(data, list(data$Species, data$Site))

 seasonCompare = lapply(newdata, function(x) {
   m.interaction = (lm(BodySize ~ SeasonGDD*Site, data = x))
   #Anova table
   anova(m.interaction)
   # Obtain slopes
   m.interaction$coefficients
   m.lst = lstrends(m.interaction, "Site", var="SeasonGDD")
   # Compare slopes
   print(pairs(m.lst))
   })
```

Here's what I'd like the output to look something like:

```
[[1]]$cockerelli.1
P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 5 estimates 
 contrast      estimate           SE  df t.ratio p.value
 1 - 2     0.0044905951 0.0020291812 525   2.213  0.1764
 1 - 3     0.0007809249 0.0004559391 525   1.713  0.4269
 1 - 4     0.0022220434 0.0004862632 525   4.570  0.0001
 1 - 5     0.0610176389 0.0141858874 525   4.301  0.0002
 2 - 3    -0.0037096702 0.0020046493 525  -1.851  0.3457

[[1]]$infrequens.1
P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 5 estimates 
 contrast      estimate           SE   df t.ratio p.value
 1 - 2    -4.003309e-04 0.0002637222 3067  -1.518  0.5508
 1 - 3    -2.272248e-04 0.0001984400 3067  -1.145  0.7825
 1 - 4    -3.664736e-04 0.0001983656 3067  -1.847  0.3464
```

Thanks so much in advance!

Undesired output:

```
contrast     estimate           SE  df t.ratio p.value
 1 - 2    -0.010726867 0.0014693633 345  -7.300  <.0001
 1 - 3    -0.008197681 0.0009939915 345  -8.247  <.0001
 1 - 4    -0.009577345 0.0010252581 345  -9.341  <.0001
 1 - 5    -0.424121019 0.0759824627 345  -5.582  <.0001
 2 - 3     0.002529186 0.0013368246 345   1.892  0.3236
 2 - 4     0.001149522 0.0013602334 345   0.845  0.9163
 2 - 5    -0.413394152 0.0759877208 345  -5.440  <.0001
 3 - 4    -0.001379664 0.0008241514 345  -1.674  0.4514
 3 - 5    -0.415923338 0.0759800152 345  -5.474  <.0001
 4 - 5    -0.414543674 0.0759804306 345  -5.456  <.0001

 P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 5 estimates  
 contrast      estimate           SE  df t.ratio p.value
 1 - 2    -3.445648e-06 0.0008580996 279  -0.004  1.0000
 1 - 3     3.055790e-03 0.0011595803 279   2.635  0.0240
 2 - 3     3.059235e-03 0.0012805524 279   2.389  0.0461
```

Comment: What is wrong with current code? Any errors? Undesired result?

Comment: Hi Parfait, no errors. The undesired result is several outputs of the text below for each list item, but without any way of knowing which list item it is for. I would like to title the output with something like [[1]]$infrequens.1, as shown above in the original question, whereas now the output I get just starts with: 
P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 5 estimates 
     contrast      estimate           SE   df t.ratio p.value
     1 - 2    -4.003309e-04 0.0002637222 3067  -1.518  0.5508
     1 - 3    -2.272248e-04 0.0001984400 3067  -1.145  0.7825, etc.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52022569/edit) your post to show the undesired result. I cannot see what you mean since `split` returns a named list of items. There is no need to repeat the desired output in your long comment.

Comment: By the way, your code never used the *x* being passed into `lapply` function. You should have received exact output for all elements.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try:

```
names(seasoneCompare) <- names(newdata)
```

Comment: Don't use lapply, use sapply - it keeps the column names

Answer (score 0):

**Don't use `lapply`, use `sapply` - it keeps the column names**.

Look how much nicer the sapply output is:

```
> df <- data.frame(one=c(1,1), foo=c(4,5))

> lapply(df, mean)
$one
[1] 1

$foo
[1] 4.5

> sapply(df, mean)
 one fuzz 
 1.0  4.5
```